# Data-Bind button Value to View Model KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I want to bind the value of a button to my blank viewmodel, how would i do it? I made this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fumunchu/qCCVe/)** to demonstrate what I ham trying to achieve.

Here is my Viewmodel:

```
var CustomerSearchViewModel = {
    SearchType: ko.observable(""),
    SearchString: ko.observable("");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(CustomerSearchViewModel);
});
```

Here is how I am trying to do the data-bind:

```
<button type="button" data-bind='value: SearchType, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' value="0" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Company Name</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this but the way how you try to use the `value` binding with the buttons won't work.

One of the easiest solutions which requires the least modification in your HTML is to use the `click` binding and set the `SearchType` in the event handler:

```
var CustomerSearchViewModel = {
       SearchType: ko.observable(""),
       SearchString: ko.observable(""),
       setSearchType : function(data, element)
       {           
           this.SearchType($(element.target).val());
       }
   };
```

Then your buttons should look like this:

```
<button type="button" data-bind='click: setSearchType'
        value="0" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Company Name</button>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ESPnc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating your model like this:

```
function CustomerSearchViewModel = {
    SearchType: ko.observable(""),
    SearchString: ko.observable(""),
    UpdateSearch: function(data, event) {
        this.SearchType($(event.target).val());
        this.SearchString($(event.target).attr('searchString'));
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(CustomerSearchViewModel);
});
```

And then in the binding add a click event to update the `SearchString`, using a custom attribute called `searchString`.  Something like this:

```
<button type="button" data-bind='click: UpdateSearch' searchString="Company Name" class="btn" value="0" data-toggle="button">Company Name</button>
```